# Fill missing data by character value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that looks like this

```
ring_no.    CR     
1           BMGG  
1           BMGG  
1
1
1
2           BMYY
2
3           BMRR
```

I'd like fill the missing data (blank cells in the df) in the CR column with character values based on the ring_no. 
I.e. 1 = BMGG, 2 = BMYY, 3 = BMRR

If possible I'd like a dplyr approach.

I hope that makes sense?

thanks

Comment: Convert the blanks to NA and use `tidyr::fill()`

Comment: thanks that seems to have worked with this -
v<-data1 %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, list(~na_if(.,""))) %>% 
  group_by(ring_no.) %>%
  fill(CR)